# How to insert a block every several div with haml?

Tags: html, ruby, haml

I want to insert a `div.row` every three blocks in order to **wrap** three `span` together for the following haml snippet.

But this code insert a `<div class="row"></div>` rather than wrap the `.span4`.

```
  - data.apps.applications.each_with_index do |app, index|
  - if index%3 == 0
    .row # This is the line I want to insert
    .span4
```

How could I do that in haml or in this case, `erb` is more suitable?

Comment: you need correct indentation for this to work

Answer (score 8):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
-data.apps.applications.each_slice(3) do |apps|
  .row
    -apps.each do |app|
      .span4
```

This uses [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice). `apps` is an array of three items from `applications`.

This takes groups of three elements from `applications`, and for each group adds a `row` div and then adds a `span4` div for each element, so what you get is something like this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>
</div>
```

If you don't have a multiple of three elements, the last group will just have one or two members.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is wrong

```
- data.apps.applications.each_with_index do |app, index|
  - if index%3 == 0
    .row # This is the line I want to insert
  .span4
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this places each `.span4` outside of the `.row`, which means the row doesn't wrap the spans