# HAML + Bootstrap div.row and div.spanX, new row every N elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282026/how-to-insert-a-block-every-several-div-with-haml), which has an answer which is exactly what I tried to start.  However, it does not yield the intended results.

Given array `@items`, I want to create a new row for every 3 items.  This is currently my markup:

```
- @items.each_with_index do |item, index|
  - if index % 3 == 0
    %div.row-fluid
  %div.span4
    %div.item-container
      use item
```

This results in html being rendered like this

```
<div class="row-fluid"></div>
<div class="span4">...</div>
<div class="span4">...</div> 
<div class="span4">...</div>
<div class="row-fluid"></div>
<div class="span4">...</div>
<div class="span4">...</div> 
<div class="span4">...</div>
```

Of course, what I want is:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">...</div>
    <div class="span4">...</div> 
    <div class="span4">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">...</div>
    <div class="span4">...</div> 
    <div class="span4">...</div>
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: you have wrong indentation in your code. `%div.span4` should be under `%div.row-fluid` not on the same level of `if` condition.

Comment: @SybariteManoj yes. That's the problem with Haml. You can't intend it under `.row-fluid` in that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Divide collection using [Array#in_groups_of](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) an then iterate it:

```
- @items = (1..20).to_a
- @items.in_groups_of(3, false).each_with_index do |group, index|
  .row-fluid
    - group.each do |item|
      .span4= "group: #{index}; item: #{item}"
```

*hint:* You can leave off the tag definition and have it default to `%div`.  `%div.span4` became just `.span4` and so on.

Comment: I had already solved it using basically the same method, but since this is the only way I have fond to do it, you get the check!