# Display container in HAML on each even column

Tags: html, conditional-statements, haml, containers, wrapper

I need to render two columns in HAML such that final output would be:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='left'>
      Some stuff's contents...
    </div>  
    <div class='right'>
      Some other stuff's contents...    
    </div>      
  </div>  
</div>
```

[image]

Apparently the following won't work.

```
.wrapper
  - @stuff.each_with_index do | stuff, index |
    - if index % 2 == 0
      .container
        = render 'stuff_partial', :stuff => stuff
    - else
      = render 'stuff_partial', :stuff => stuff
```

I tried to use HAML's **surround** method, but I don't understand how can I get two columns be nested **inside** the condition? In HTML you would only write two conditions for the **container's** opening and closing tags and that's it. Is there any method in HAML for  doing just that?

Answer (score 1):

So I found a direction to my answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282026/how-to-insert-a-block-every-several-div-with-haml). And the answer is,

```
.wrapper
  - @stuff.each_slice(2) do | stuff |
    .container
      - stuffs.each_with_index do | stuff, index |
        - if index % 2 == 0
          = render 'stuff_partial', :locals => { :stuff => stuff, class => 'left' } 
        - else
          = render 'stuff_partial', :locals => { :stuff => stuff, class => 'right' }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do that using the surround tag, you would have to do it as so:

```
.wrapper
  - @stuff.each_with_index do | stuff, index |
    - surround(index % 2 ? "<div class='container'>" : "", index % 2 ? "</div>" : "") do
      = render 'stuff_partial', :stuff => stuff
```

However, just because you can do it does not mean you should.  Two claimed benefits of HAML is the easy readability and the guarantee that it is producing valid HTML/XML.  In this case, you are introducing code that harms readability as well as providing an easy opportunity for having a bug that prevents you from having valid HTML/XML.

My recommendation is to instead use the if statement and use partials to reduce duplication.  An alternative is to use ERB instead which would allow you to conditionally include the parent elements.